# Coninuous webjob vs triggered for a scheduled run

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered, azure-webjobs-continuous

I am having a webjob which needs to run at regular intervals but having it as continuous with cron expression rather than triggered type.
Will it make any difference especially in terms of any performance? 
Any help in understanding this very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous webjob for a schedule run: It will starts immediately when the WebJob is created and run on the schedule.

Triggered webjob for a scheduled run: Starts only when triggered on a schedule.

If your app runs continuous or scheduled WebJobs, enable `Always On` to ensure that the WebJobs run reliably. This feature is available only in the Basic, Standard, and Premium pricing tiers.

Comment: Thank you but do you know how it impacts performance if I put continuous with timer than triggered with timer

Comment: Continuous timer will always running job while triggered run on schedule. Also, continuous will runs on all instances that the web app runs on while triggered job can run for long running process but only single instance of Job will run.

Comment: Thank you, so I assume unless it runs on two server I don't see any problem